# jQuery Mobile Page Transition Problems

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, transition

After clicking back and forth between two separate pages (done via ajax) the pages begin to jump back the to other without my input. For example, if I have pg 1 and pg 2. I'll click back and forth between 1 and 2 a few times and then at some point when I click 2, it will load then immediately go back to 1. fyi..removing the ajax loading fixes the problem.

I am using the following libraries on my page:
 - PhoneGap
 - jQuery Mobile
 - iScroll
 - Modernizr

Any idea on what's happening here?

Comment: Example code or a http://jsfiddle.net would help

Comment: it turned out to be an iScroll conflict with jQuery. I've put it aside for a bit. when I get back to it and find a solution I'll post it.

Answer (score 1):

it seems a problem I had some time ago with jqm. When you have loaded and reloaded many pages it seems that the actions you take are executing more than once. I solved it unbinding (undelegating...)  instructions like this:

```
$('div').bind('click', function(){ ... });
```

for:

```
$('div').unbind('click').bind('click', function(){ ... });
```

Proceeding this way the handler will only call the function once, because the unbind call tells ajax to release it.

Anyways, I'm pretty sure it's not the best behaviour, so I think it should be some better way to solve this issues, but I don't know it ;)